# Does sync work on Firefox Lite for Android

Tags: browser, firefox-for-android

As a privacy conscious user I am trying to decouple as much as possible from our internet overlords Google, Facebook, Twitter et al. To that end I have decided to shift from using Google Chrome to Firefox as my primary web browser both on my computer as well as my Android mobile device.

The main Firefox app for Android is quite big, and there is a smaller substitute for called Firefox lite. My preference is to use Firefox lite but it is essential for me to be able to sync my bookmarks and saved logins across my computer and mobile device. While the main Firefox app allows me to sync, I haven't been able to figure out how to sync over the Firefox lite app. Has the sync feature been excluded for this "lite" version of Firefox?

Comment: Synchronization is not mentioned in the app description of the lite version but on the full version it is mentioned.